# What is the equivalent of mockito's spy in jmock 2?

Tags: java, mocking, tdd, mockito, jmock

In mockito we are able to spy on real instance as in:

```
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    List<String> spy = spy(list);
    spy.add("one");
    verify(spy).add("one");
```

What would be the equivalent of spy functionality in jmock 2?

Comment: Reverse of this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6565971/1686291

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I don't think that question is related to my question. It's more related to the [JMock States](http://www.jmock.org/states.html) functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito's "spies" are also known as "partial" mocks. jMock, however, has no support for partial mocking or "spying". (At least, I couldn't find anything of the sort in jMock's [API documentation](http://www.jmock.org/javadoc/jmock-2.6.0/doc/index.html)).